# How can I separate the horizontal rule from the table. They are mixed together. I want the horizontal rule below my table

Tags: html, html-table

[My horizontal rule is mixed up with part of the information on a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDRoV.png)

So, my issue is to create two separate tables side by side, instead of one table below the other like usual. I did something that made it work but now my `<hr>` tag is mixed together with the tables.

```html
<h3>Skills</h3>
<table style="float: left">
   <tr>
      <td>Sleeping</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Eating</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table style="float: left">
   <tr>
      <td>Gaming</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Reading</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
</table>
<hr size="3" noshade="3">
```

That is the code. Can someone please help me put the horizontal rule below the table? As you can see from my code, the hr tag comes after closing the second table tag but my final output has mixed up the horizontal rule together with the table, instead of below it. What error have I made in my code? Any help would be appreciated, especially from my code. Somebody advise me on what's wrong with my code.

Also, I'm not pretty sure what is the work of the div tag since this was kinda an assignment if anybody can explain to me well, and why I put it in my code, I honestly don't know.

Comment: If you make something use `float`, it will not push everything else to the next line. It will let them be rendered in the same line as the `float`ed element. That's the purpose of `float`.

Comment: Pardon. What's the purpose of float again?

Comment: It just controls the gravity of an object. Whether it will be pushed left or right (or none). All its neighbors would normally wrap around it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table {
  float: left
}

hr {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<h3>Skills</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Sleeping</td>
    <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eating</td>
    <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="float: left">
  <tr>
    <td>Gaming</td>
    <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reading</td>
    <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
</table>
<hr size="3" noshade="3">
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your CSS tag, the hr { clear both; }, what does it do?

Comment: it makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Change the styles of the `<table>`s to be `display`ed as `inline`:

```
<h3>Skills</h3>
<table style="display:inline">
   <tr>
      <td>Sleeping</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Eating</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table style="display: inline">
   <tr>
      <td>Gaming</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Reading</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
</table>
<hr size="3" noshade="3">
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jag2bqcu/).

Comment: What does changing the styles of the table to be displayed as inline do?

Comment: Makes the tables render in the same line as its neighbors. `<hr />` elements are displayed as `block` instead, so they're not inline. So they will automatically go to a new line. Checkout the Property Values section here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just an educated guess at this stage you have two
 `<table style="float: left">` have you tried
 `<table style="float: right">` for your second table? instead of left? Hope this helps!!

Comment: I'm new to float, I guess I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

## I've found the solution

I just had to put my two tables inside one main table, the two tables would be table data inside table rows

```
    <h3>Skills</h3>
<table cellspacing="10">
  <td>
  <table cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>Sleeping</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eating</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
<td>
  <table cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>Gaming</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Reading</td>
      <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</td>
  </table>
</td>
</table>
```